# Gnumake cross product target matching

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to combine different aspects into simple recipes with `make`.
Essentially, I am handling raw data and want to process it in a cross-product fashion.

I have input files

```
processing-scripts
├── all.awk
├── amd.awk
├── avg.awk
├── gm.awk
├── intel.awk
└── process.awk
processing-p256-mul
├── cycle.raw
├── mem.raw
├── total.raw
└── xmm.raw
Makefile
```

and my Makefile

```makefile
GM_METRICS=cycle
AVG_METRICS=total xmm mem
METRICS=$(addsuffix .avg,$(AVG_METRICS)) $(addsuffix .gm,$(GM_METRICS))
ARCH=amd intel all
process-p256-mul: METHOD=p256-mul
process-p256-mul: $(addprefix processing-p256-mul/,$(foreach arch,$(addsuffix .,$(ARCH)), $(addprefix $(arch),$(METRICS))))

%/total.in: %/total.raw
    sed -e 's@ \([0-9]*\)\r@:\1\r@' $(<) > $(@)
%/cycle.in: %/cycle.raw
    sed -e 's@   *\([0-9]\+\).*(\(.*\))@\2:\1@' $(<) | grep -v Cycles > $(@)
%/xmm.in: %/xmm.raw
    cp $(<) $(@)
%/mem.in: %/mem.raw
    cp $(<) $(@)

amd.%.avg: %.in
    awk -f ./processing-scripts/amd.awk   -f ./processing-scripts/avg.awk -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
amd.%.gm: %.in
    awk -f ./processing-scripts/amd.awk   -f ./processing-scripts/gm.awk  -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
intel.%.avg: %.in
    awk -f ./processing-scripts/intel.awk -f ./processing-scripts/avg.awk -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
intel.%.gm: %.in
    awk -f ./processing-scripts/intel.awk -f ./processing-scripts/gm.awk  -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
all.%.avg: %.in
    awk -f ./processing-scripts/all.awk   -f ./processing-scripts/avg.awk -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
all.%.gm: %.in
    awk -f ./processing-scripts/all.awk   -f ./processing-scripts/gm.awk  -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
```

Each different type of raw file, needs different preprocessing, `total` needs this simple `sed` expression, `cycle` needs a bit more complicated one, `xmm` and `mem` only needs a simple copy. That works fine.
Now what I want to improve is the last part.

I need to generate (`bash`-like expansion syntax) `{intel,amd,all}.{{total,xmm,mem}.avg,cycle.gm}`.

(disregard for now everything below the `process-p256-mul` rule)
Running `make process-p256-mul -nk` gives me what I expect:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/amd.total.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/amd.xmm.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/amd.mem.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/amd.cycle.gm', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/intel.total.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/intel.xmm.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/intel.mem.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/intel.cycle.gm', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/all.total.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/all.xmm.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/all.mem.avg', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'processing-p256-mul/all.cycle.gm', needed by 'process-p256-mul'.
```

Now adding the `*in: *raw` recipes back in will generate the correct preprocessing rules. And adding the last six recipes in will also print the correct process commands.

My question is how do I write the last rules without being so verbose. Semantically:

```makefile
%1.%2.%3: %1.%2.in
     awk -f ./processing-scripts/%1.awk   -f ./processing-scripts/%3.awk -f ./processing-scripts/process.awk $(<) >$(@)
```

I feel like I could get around the problem in the command with `$(basename $<)` and `$(basename $(basename $@))` but how would I make the target match to begin with?

PS: I'm also more than happy for advice on the foreach, if there is maybe a dedicated command for this... Feels a bit wrong. Or maybe point to a similar question, I'm struggling with finding the right keywords for my search. (As you can see in the title)

Comment: I feel like you are treading very close to where perhaps `make` should no longer be your tool of choice. I have set up similar sprawling `Makefiles` in the past and they were just too monstrous to be useful. `make` makes sense (pardon the pun) when you have fairly linear relationships, but turns into just another kind of unmaintainable spaghetti code which is hard to get right and impossible to maintain over time when you try to use it over a wide matrix.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I've edited the question, and changed the commands from the peudocode, Did you mean that, or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes GNU `make`. There are 3 different problems to solve:

- Compute the list of targets; you apparently know how to do this with the make functions, so let's skip this (but see below a slightly simpler solution than yours).
- Associate targets and prerequisites; this is the tricky part. There are basically two options: `foreach-eval-call` and secondary expansion.
- Write the recipes; here also there are several options to extract the architecture name and the `avg` or `gm` suffix; this is straightforward with `foreach-eval-call`, a bit more tricky with secondary expansion.

With `foreach-eval-call`:

```
define MY_RULE
$1.%.$2: %.in
     awk -f processing-scripts/$1.awk -f processing-scripts/$2.awk \
       -f processing-scripts/process.awk $$< > $$@
endef
$(foreach a,$(ARCH),$(foreach b,avg gm,$(eval $(call MY_RULE,$a,$b))))
```

See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) for the detailed explanation about `foreach-eval-call`. Pay attention to the `$$` in the macro definition they are essential.

With secondary expansion and make functions for the recipe:

```
TARGETS := $(foreach a,$(ARCH),$(addprefix processing-p256-mul/$a.,$(METRICS)))
process-p256-mul: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(TARGETS): $$(@D)/$$(word 2,$$(subst ., ,$$(@F))).in
    awk -f processing-scripts/$(word 1,$(subst ., ,$(@F))).awk \
      -f processing-scripts/$(word 3,$(subst ., ,$(@F))).awk \
      -f processing-scripts/process.awk $< > $@
```

As suggested by [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) you could also use shell substitutions to extract the architecture and the suffix in the recipe:

```
$(TARGETS): $$(@D)/$$(word 2,$$(subst ., ,$$(@F))).in
    f=$(@F); a=$${f%%.*}; m=$${f##*.}; \
    awk -f processing-scripts/$$a.awk -f processing-scripts/$$m.awk \
      -f processing-scripts/process.awk $< > $@
```

See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) for the detailed explanation about secondary expansion. Here too, pay attention to the `$$` in the prerequisites list and in the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the recipe, you can use the shell to extract the different components from the target names.  You will need a separate pattern rule for each metric (thanks @RenaudPacalet), but you can avoid code duplication by putting the rule body (which is the same for both rules) in a variable:

```
# ...

PROCESSING = full='$@'; arch="$${full%%.*}" metric="$${full\#\#*.}"; \
        awk -f "./processing-scripts/$${arch}.awk" \
            -f "./processing-scripts/$${metric}.awk" \
            -f  ./processing-scripts/process.awk

%.avg: %.in
        $(PROCESSING) $< >$@

%.gm: %.in
        $(PROCESSING) $< >$@
```

That's pretty clear and easy(-ish) to understand and maintain.

Comment: You do not address the dependencies issue. It is not `%.avg: %.in`, it is `process-p256-mul/intel.%.avg: process-p256-mul/%.in` (same for all architectures and also for `gm`).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet this follows the lead of the rules presented in the question by the OP.  The question asserts that those work, and asks for a way to simplify them.  Furthermore, these rules will work just fine for targets and prerequisites that have a (consistent) directory prefix.  The `%` in the patterns will match that.  It will match other things too, of course, so a directory prefix could be added to make them more specific.

Comment: Well, if you look at their working example you see `amd.%.avg: %.in`, not `%.avg: %.in`. They want `DIR/amd.total.avg` to depend on `DIR/total.in` (their version), not `DIR/amd.total.in` (yours).